# How to tell Proguard to maintain same obfuscated names across builds

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

Say I have 2 classes -
`my.Class1 and my.Class2`
which obfuscate to 
`a.A & a.B`
respectively.

How do i ensure `my.Class1 and my.Class2` retain the obfuscated name of `a.A and a.B` across builds as I add/remove other classes or upgrade proguard version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [-printmapping](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#printmapping) in the first pass, and [-applymapping](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#applymapping) in the second pass.